# I am trying to download a file from mysql, I saved the file location in the database, now I am trying to make a download link for the user on my page

Tags: php, mysql

Unable to create the download link. I am fetching the path saved from database and then try to make a link for it to download, but nothing happens.
Below is my code:

```
$query_print="SELECT vitae_pi FROM pi WHERE username='t124'";
$query_print_run=mysqli_query($conn,$query_print);
$query_print_recordset=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_print_run);
$query_print_path=$query_print_recordset['vitae_pi'];
echo ' this is file path '.$query_print_path;
```

Here I am simply trying to create the download link for user t124, instead of using the current user for testing purposes?
This is hyperlink code:

```
<?php echo "<a href='".$query_print_path."'>".DOWNLOAD."</a>"; ?>
```

Any suggestions?

This my move file function:

```
protected function moveFile($file)
{
    $filename = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
    //echo $filename;
    $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $filename);
    if ($success) {
        $result = $file['name'] . ' was uploaded successfully';
        if (!is_null($this->newName)) {
            $_SESSION['current_filename']=$this->newName;
            echo $_SESSION['current_filename'];
            $result .= ', and was renamed ' . $this->newName;
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['current_filename']=$file['name'];
            echo $_SESSION['current_filename'];
        }
        //$result .= '.';

        //echo $this->newName;
        $this->messages[] = $result;
    } else {
        $this->messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $file['name'];
    }
}
```

Updating the table with file path:

```
    $file_path_variable1= $destination1.$_SESSION['current_filename'];
echo '$file_path_variable1 : '.$file_path_variable1;

$query1="UPDATE proposal SET whitepaper_prop='$file_path_variable1' WHERE userName_prop='$currentuser'";
$result_query1=mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
```

....................
SOLUTION CODE IS:
Solution code is :

```
$query_print="SELECT vitae_pi FROM pi WHERE username='t115'";
$query_print_run=mysqli_query($conn,$query_print);
$query_print_recordset=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_print_run);
$query_print_path=$query_print_recordset['vitae_pi'];
$dir= 'uploaded/';
$path=opendir($dir);
<?php 
}while($query_pi_array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_pi_result));?>
<div>
<?php while($file=readdir($path)){
  if($file != "." || $file !=".."){
  if($file==$query_print_path){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $dir.$query_print_path; ?>">Proposal Whitepaper</a>
```

Comment: do you have a `define('DOWNLOAD', $query_print_path)` somewhere in your code? How do you expect `DOWNLOAD` to have a value, when you're fetching your database value into `$query_print_path`?

Comment: No I am not expecting DOWNLOAD to have any values, I just used it as a hyperlink text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does this display ?

```
<?php echo "<a href='".$query_print_path."'>".DOWNLOAD."</a>"; ?>
```

DOWNLOAD should be part of the PHP string, if not, it will be considered as a constant :

```
<?php echo "<a href='".$query_print_path."'>DOWNLOAD</a>"; ?>
```

Also, use double quotes for HTML attributes :

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"$query_print_path\">DOWNLOAD</a>"; ?>
```

And the optimized way (to avoid useless string parsing) :

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.$query_print_path.'">DOWNLOAD</a>'; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying,
I get this output:
c:xampphtdocspi_co_pi/uploaded/salsaBOY_30.pdf
 It should be ideally c:/xampp/htdocspi_co_pi/uploaded/salsaBOY_30.pdf I think with back slashes. Any suggestions..?

Comment: That means your path is originally wrong, in your database. So you have to look somewhere else, where you actually put that data in the database

Comment: Tarik Zouine: This is my move file function, I cant see anything wrong this, can may be have a look at it..?

Comment: protected function moveFile($file)
{ $filename = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
//echo $filename;
$success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $filename);
if ($success) {
$result = $file['name'] . ' was uploaded successfully';
if (!is_null($this->newName)) {
$_SESSION['current_filename']=$this->newName;
echo $_SESSION['current_filename'];
$result .= ', and was renamed ' . $this->newName;
} else{
$_SESSION['current_filename']=$file['name'];
echo $_SESSION['current_filename'];
}//$result .= '.';
//echo $this->newName;
$this->messages[] = $result;

Comment: ;
} else {
$this->messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $file['name'];}}

Comment: Could you please update your question and use the code formatting ?

Comment: We still cannot see how you put your file path in your database ... Also, what do you have into $this->destination ?

Comment: I think you should have backslashes and not slashes in you (windows) path. Did you use any function to replace backslashes by slashes ? Another way would be to use the addslashes() PHP function, which will double backslash your backslashes.

Comment: I just updated the part where I am updating the table with the file path name. You mean after fetching the path from the file path from database i should run this function addslashes() on it..?

Comment: addslashes() is supposed to be used right before insertion in database. Cause if you have something like c:\new then the \n will be interpretated as a new line. Can you show us the result printed when you print $file_path_variable1 ?

Comment: This is what I get for $file_path_variable1 : C:\xampp\htdocs\pi_co_pi/uploaded/tangoBoy_45

but this is what gets saved to database: C:xampphtdocspi_co_pi/uploaded/salsaBOY_30.pdf

Comment: Good to know you originally have a proper path. So you can now use addslashes right before the SQL insert query. Use stripslashes() to remove these additional backslashes when you'll get the data from the database

Comment: I have not used stripslashes(), I get this when I fetch path from database : c:\xampp\htdocs\pi_co_pi/uploaded/tangoBoy_49.pdf
this still does not open the file location, seems like forward slashes added to later half of the path is the problem.. suggestion..?

Comment: Got it thanks for help Tarik Zouine,
Solution code is (UPDATED QUESTION TOO):
$query_print="SELECT vitae_pi FROM pi WHERE username='t115'";
$query_print_run=mysqli_query($conn,$query_print);
$query_print_recordset=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_print_run);
$query_print_path=$query_print_recordset['vitae_pi'];
$dir= 'uploaded/';
$path=opendir($dir);
<?php 
}while($query_pi_array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_pi_result));?>
<div>
<?php while($file=readdir($path)){
  if($file != "." || $file !=".."){
  if($file==$query_print_path){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $dir.$query_print_path; ?>">Proposal Whitepaper</a>